# Windows Phone 7 and Back button Guidelines

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm reading the following sumission requirement:

*To maintain a consistent user experience, the Back button must only be used for backwards navigation in the application.*

*a. Pressing the Back button from the first screen of an application must exit the application.

b.  Pressing the Back button must return the application to the previous page.

c. If the current page displays a context menu or a dialog, the pressing of the Back button must close the menu or dialog and cancel the backward navigation to the previous page.

d. For games, when the Back button is pressed during gameplay, the game can choose to present a pause context menu or dialog or navigate the user to the prior menu screen. Pressing the Back button again while in a paused context menu or dialog closes the menu or dialog.*

My application require LogIn the first time, before entering its MainPage.
The login data will not be asked again (the user can change account from the settings).

I would like to avoid user entering again in the login page by using the backstack.
Pressing back from MainPage will exit the application.

In particular I'm worried about:
a. I show as a first screen the login page which will navigate to the mainpage, but I'm exiting the app with a back from the mainpage
b. I'm skipping a page, so pressing back is not strictly going to the previouspage

Do you think it will satisfy the certification requirements ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This scenario is allowed, what you should do is:

upon entering the MainPage (OnNavigatedTo) - remove one page from the back stack:

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Read this thread on the Windows Phone forum](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/77729/471676.aspx)

The most important part appears to be that you should never disable the back button but I do think that according to this thread that it is allowed to skip the login screen.

On the other hand you might want to rethink the flow of the application when you consider thombstoning and re-activating; should the user login again and what would a natural flow be?